# how to pass variables between complex python class and function?

Tags: python

one input

one output

I want to get output through one long process.Because the process is so long, I have to continue input and return output. Is there some convenient way to get output inside the class or function without pass one function and other?

the demo function as follows:

main.py

```
from run import class1
def f1(input):
    c=class1()
    output=c.cf2(input)
    return output
```

run.py

```
class1(input):
    def cf1(input):
        ca=class2()
        output=ca.c2f1(input)
        return output
    def cf2(input):
        output=self.cf1(input)
        return output

class2():
    def c2f1(user_input):
        variable=user_input
        output=self.c2f2(variable)
        return output

     def c2f2():
         y=…
         return y
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still can't understand what are you trying to obtain. Like in this code, what are you trying to optimize?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you trying to find a way to stream data, without reading all the input in advance? Or is it something else?

Comment: simply put, delete 4 "return output "in demo case. pass output from c2f1 to f1 directly

Comment: Do cf1 and cf2 actually do anything? Do they modify the input? If not, why not call c2f1 directly?

Comment: yes, they do something which i didn't write here. I can get result only after all the process finished. by the way, the reason why i asked this question is that I want to make a website which show result at one page. The code was written a long time ago when I just   used for myself. I can print the result on terminal directly. But now I need to pass the variable through a long process